# birthdayContactIdentifier BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, ekevent

When I access the property birthdayContactIdentifier from EKEvent I always instantly get a BAD_ACCESS error (not even able to nil check)

This is the code I am using to fetch

```
import UIKit  
import EventKit  
class ViewController: UIViewController {  

let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()  
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()  

    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event) { (granted, error) in  
        if granted == true {  
            let startDate = NSDate()  
            let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(7.0*86400.0)  

            let events = self.eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(self.eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: nil))  

            for event in events {  
                if event.calendar.type == .Birthday {  
                    NSLog("\(event.title)")  
                    NSLog("\(event.birthdayContactIdentifier)") // BAD_ACCESS  
                }  
            }  
        }  
     }   
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found bug number 22475180 [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17385). Try birthdayPersonID. It is currently deprecated as of iOS 9, but it might work differently

Comment: I had also found that one earlier, apple hasn't given any solution on it unfortunately. I'll try birthdayPersonID though its likely that it won't be compatible with Contacts framework. But i will try and report back.

Comment: Just tried with birthdayPersonID, doesn't give any errors but the identifier is different so it won't fetch the right contact.

Comment: How do you verify it's different if birthdayContactIdentifier faults? (Wondering if there's a clue there)

Comment: I've printed Contact framework contacts identifiers before and they we're in a different format. (Contacts = XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX) (AddressBook = Int)

Comment: How did you access them?

Comment: Well i already have contacts integrated for other functionality, so just through CNContact.identifier. And ABPersonRef uses an int as identifier, and thus can never be in the same format as CNContact.identifier